# Cocos2d: is there a way to access to a CCMenu child?

Tags: menu, cocos2d-iphone, menuitem, switching

I am using the following code:

```
CCMenuItemFont *controllerItem = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString:@"Analog" target:self selector:@selector(controllerToggle)];

    CCMenu *controllerTypeMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:controllerItem, nil];
    [controllerTypeMenu alignItemsVerticallyWithPadding:30.0f];
    controllerTypeMenu.position = CGPointMake(160.0f, 240.0f);
    [self addChild:controllerTypeMenu z:0 tag:ControllerMenu];
}  

-(void) controllerToggle
{
    CCMenuItemFont *controllerItem = [self getChildByTag:888];
    NSString * text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"switching.. %f", CCRANDOM_0_1()];
    [controllerItem setString:text];
}
```

In controllerToggle I would like to access to controllerItem and change the String to another value. Is this possible? I checked and CCMenu adds as child the CCMenuItems based the array order. But that's not an elegant solution. For the same reason I cannot add the CCMenuItem to the Scene as it will give me "child already added error". So I feel I should write my own "switch" button but I wonder if there is already something out there..

Any help?? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can declare needed menu item as class member. In this way you will be able to get access to it whenever you want

Comment: Ah ok, so I won't have to add them as child and I can still access them. Nice one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is already CCMenuItemToogle which is used to switching the title or image of any menuitem on click event.Instead of taking CCMenuItem you can use CCMenuItemToggle..

Here is a sample code
CCmenuItemToggle  *cam=[CCMenuItemToggle itemWithTarget:self selector:@selector(openCameraController) items:cameraOn,cameraOff, nil];
where cameraOn and cameraOff are two simple CCMenuItemImage which is added in CCMenuItemToggle and further this CCmenuItemToggle is added in a menu.

Now on every click of CCMenuItemToggle there will be a cameraOn and cameraOff state for same menuitem.

Hope this will help...

Comment: I was not looking for a toggle, I had found that one but I needed more than 2 states (E.g. radio button). Hence the answer above is good and then I found also CCRadio implementation here: http://d1xzuxjlafny7l.cloudfront.net/downloads/CCRadioMenu.zip